# to clean and short the using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I know many user have asked this question but i have tried everything still not understand the problem

I have url like this 
`http://localhost/test/storelocator.php?page=store`

Now i want to like this 
`http://localhost/spawake/storelocator`

My htaccess

```
# Turn Rewrite Engine On
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite for storelocator.php
RewriteRule ^storelocator storelocator.php [NC, L]
```

but showing me the error in all the pages **Internal Server Error** So anyone can plz hep

Comment: What is the error message you see? Please look into your http servers error log file. Most likely the rewriting module simply is not available...

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove space after `NC`
2. Disable `MultiViews` option
3. Restrict your pattern by using end anchor.

Your .htaccess:

```
Option -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /spawake/fbdemo/

# Rewrite for storelocator.php
RewriteRule ^storelocator/?$ storelocator.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: The requested URL /spawake/fbdemo/storelocator was not found on this server.

Comment: I have spawake folder and then I have fbdemo folder so i have put my .htacces to fbdemo folder

Comment: Nope but instead of this I have made a folder name storelocator  which has index file . index file has a redirect to the page i wanted , so it solve my problem .

Comment: ok glad you resolved your current problem but creating folder is not always possible